# Login / Register for specific pages

Tags: login

I would like to limit specific pages to only logged in users.

Let me point out, that I would not like to use /wp-admin login.
I would not like users to acces /wp-admin login page, but some sort of custom administration module that would allow me to limit pages/posts to only logged in users.

Is there any plugin that works this way or is the only way to limit pages by user type with/wp-admin login page.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins you can use, [UserPro](https://codecanyon.net/item/userpro-user-profiles-with-social-login/5958681) does what you want – it lets you control access rights for users, and the users don't use the WordPress admin interface, rather a front end interface.

There are plenty of free alternatives as well, a quick [Google search](https://www.google.no/search?q=restrict%20access%20wp) will give you plenty to choose from.